# Add a button to a Container

Tags: flutter, dart, button, flutter2.0

This is my Code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OverViewList extends StatefulWidget {
  OverViewList({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OverViewListState createState() => _OverViewListState();
}

class _OverViewListState extends State<OverViewList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              var showData = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: showData.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 0, 12, 0),
                      child: Card(
                        child: ListTile(
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 5, 5, 5),
                          title: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 10),
                            child: Text(showData[index]["Product_Name"]),
                          ),
                          subtitle: Text("Vorhanden: " +
                              showData[index]["Stock"] +
                              "\n" +
                              "Verdirbt am " +
                              showData[index]["Expiry_date"]),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              }

              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
            future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(
                "lib/global/Overview_Products/Overview_Product.json"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have already tried a bit around, but have not found a solution. With 'row' or 'columnß' I have also already gebeiotet. However, this does not quite work with the listview.
The button should be visible above the listview, floating, in a kind of bar at the bottom. It should be look like this:
[An example of what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVpMn.png)

Comment: Where do you want the Button? Do you want a button at the end of each individual ListTime or below the ListView?

Comment: The CircularProgressIndicator is not shown after the view list, because it is shown meanwhile the file is loading. You should write : if ( shapshot.hasData) {---- } else { return CircularProgressIndicator(...) ; } to be more clear.

Comment: In the ListBuilder Flutter  shows a list of  ListView items ( built in the builder function). Thus if you want to add a widget for every item you should wrap  the widgets :   Padding -> Card -> ListTile with a  Column(...) or Flex(...), where you can specify which item should Expand.

Comment: Thanks, but as i have edited i only want to have one Button, wich is independent to how many tiles i have in my list,  to "add" or "refresh" the list, something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the column, adding shrinkWrap:true to the listView should be enough to avoid overflow

Comment: It´s under the listview or above, but not over it. Also the Listview isn´t scrollable anymore and if there are to many items, there is an overflow. Thanks always

Comment: Adding SingleChildScrollVIew at the toppest level should solve the overflow, and adding physics should resolve scrolling problem

Answer (score 0):

If am not wrong you need a floating action button and you should check that article => [FloatingActionButton class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html)